# Can you get external IP address from within a Google Compute VM instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Querying the network interface will only return the internal instance IP address info.
Is it possible to get external IP address info from somewhere inside the running instance?

As an example, AWS has a metadata REST endpoint for instance info:
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4`

(source: http://tech-queries.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/how-to-get-public-ip-for-amazon-ec2.html)

Comment: Update: Turns out there is a metadata endpoint. For the sake of anyone else with this question - you can simply execute `curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip`

Comment: Consider moving your comment to an answer, so you can mark this question answered. That way other people will know it has been answered when they're searching (and you'll get credit for the answer!).

Comment: Update2: Google changed the DOMAIN for metadata: `curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip`  see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying

Answer (score 36):

You can get the public IP address with an HTTP GET of `http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip`. You must set the `Metadata-Flavor: Google` in HTTP header as per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/metadata#querying).

Comment: Just for references, at the time of writing this comment, the phrase `external-ip` is nowhere to be found in the linked documentation, but the answer is still working as expected.

Comment: How do we get internal-ip?

Comment: @OliverDixon The `hostname -i` command should give you the internal IP address

Answer (score 30):

Here are the links for getting Public IPv4 on various clouds.

Azure

```
curl -H Metadata:true "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance/network/interface/0/ipv4/ipAddress/0/publicIpAddress?api-version=2017-08-01&format=text"
```

AWS

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

GCP

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip
```

Since `169.254.169.254` is a global metadata server for these above cloud vendors, no need to use different domain names.